# My Facebook streaming code doesn't work anymore, FB want user to click on Go live, page admin may not be available at the time of video shooting

Tags: facebook, live-streaming, rtmps

I was using RTMP FFmpeg to streaming to the facebook, things work fine but it looks like Facebook now want the user to click on the live video on facebook.com to go live. This thing add the complexity that for example in a company 5 people are working and live streaming a video project and suddenly senior leave his office and go home early, he is the only person who has the facebook-page admin access, now video will not go live because of the requirement of click on live video on facebook UI.

Is facebook have something for this condition. I mean I use RTMP protocol in a software so people can do whatever they can easily and without having technical knowledge. I don't want the person to click on Go live every time he is using the software. Anyone have a solution for trouble like this.

Note: I am writing this question since it's related to facebook development and they told me to use StackOverflow for all dev related query.

Comment: _“he is the only person who has the facebook-page admin access, now video will not go live because of the requirement of click on live video on facebook UI.”_ - well then they can either stay, or make someone else a page admin too ...? The video being “live” and “person in control effed-off home” would be kinda contradictory to begin with IMHO.